# How to hide source and design buttons (Flash Builder)?

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I am using Flash Builder 4.6, I want find a way to hide source & design buttons or I can switch active buttons from white to gray or lavender (because I prefer working at night, dark tones will make my eyes feel pleasant)

[image]

Do you have any idea, please!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to make a button hidden you can set the visible property false under whatever criteria you want it to be hidden. To change color, look in the properties window of the component to view properties you wish to change and modify them in similar fashion.

```
if(condition){ sourceButton.visible = false; }
```